# Firefox quantum: svg attribute invalid when unit is not specified

Tags: firefox, svg, specifications

Firefox Quantum has a bug that refuses to accept SVG attribute values that does not have units, specifically the font-size attribute. According to SVG specifications, if there are no units, the default “px” will be applied, therefore if your SVG has font-size=”45″, then it is understood as font-size=”45px”. But in Quantum it will be invalid.

Here is the specification link: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#Units

Screenshot of the highlighted specs:
[image]

Edit: Sorry for the delay, was pretty occupied. This is the svg I tested with, just copy paste this and save as svg. It has font-size of "45" not "45px". You can see the font size of the text will render properly in Chrome, Safari and Opera but not in Firefox Quantum and IE.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="350" height="75" viewBox="0 0 350 75">
<title>MultiStroke</title>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="350" height="75" style="fill: #09f"/>
<g style="overflow:hidden; text-anchor: middle; font-size:45; font-weight: bold; font-family: Impact">
  <text x="175" y="55" style="fill: white; stroke: #0f9; stroke-width: 14"> Stroked Text </text>
  <text x="175" y="55" style="fill: white; stroke: #99f; stroke-width: 8"> Stroked Text </text>
  <text x="175" y="55" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2"> Stroked Text </text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Do you have a testcase? There are lots of regression tests in the Firefox build that as far as I can tell would prevent this bug. Despite the wording of the question you may be trying to do this with CSS instead of attributes and CSS **does** require units.

Comment: What is the question? Also, [can't repro](https://jsfiddle.net/feszmr69/) on FF 61 on osX.

Comment: @kaiido this happens on the latest version v.60.0.2

Comment: Please provide a reproduceable example. (in the question itself)

Comment: @RobertLongson  This is the sample testcase.

Comment: @NarenthiraRao as I said in my first comment, that's a CSS style, not an attribute.

Comment: @RobertLongson Now I understood what you mean. Was confused for a moment there. Now that you mentioned it  I will have a look again at the specs. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You say attribute but you actually use a CSS style in your question

```
style="overflow:hidden; text-anchor: middle; font-size:45; font-weight: bold; font-family: Impact"
```

That's CSS and units have always been [mandatory in CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-size-prop).

```
font-size="45"
```

that's an attribute, units are optional in SVG here.

Chrome, Safari and Opera are not following the CSS specification correctly if they allow unitless font sizes in CSS. Note that this is not a change in Firefox Quantum, all versions of Firefox work like this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.